# Why am i getting [topic-reader] [DOTJ013E][ERROR] Failed to parse the referenced file 'xxx' in DITA-OT 3.0.4

Tags: xerces, dita-ot

I'm trying to upgrade to DITA-OT 3.0.4 from 1.8.5. So i did some trial and errors.

I have a specialized SIDSC Component. In the previous version of DITA-OT it was parsed without any problem and I was able to generate the PDF. But in 3.0.4, i'm getting this error:

```
topic-reader:
[topic-reader] Reading file:/C:/InfoShare/Data/PublishingService/Data/DataExports/GUID-CE32C6F9-B88A-4E25-B702-C484D3460BCA.1129492.20180621060207637/2/en-US/workset/temp/f413807680e5a768d5bc8cf7f9e40b9bd67490f1.ditamap
[topic-reader] Processing file:/C:/InfoShare/Data/PublishingService/Data/DataExports/GUID-CE32C6F9-B88A-4E25-B702-C484D3460BCA.1129492.20180621060207637/2/en-US/workset/GUID-0D9FFE68-743C-4F90-837A-07E9F2088225.xml to file:/C:/InfoShare/Data/PublishingService/Data/DataExports/GUID-CE32C6F9-B88A-4E25-B702-C484D3460BCA.1129492.20180621060207637/2/en-US/workset/temp/9b37d86563b268e88ad9d0bfb362fddd04aa5d56.xml
[topic-reader] [DOTJ013E][ERROR] Failed to parse the referenced file 'file:/C:/InfoShare/Data/PublishingService/Data/DataExports/GUID-CE32C6F9-B88A-4E25-B702-C484D3460BCA.1129492.20180621060207637/2/en-US/workset/GUID-0D9FFE68-743C-4F90-837A-07E9F2088225.xml'.: An element type is required in the declaration of element type "desc".
```

Here is a sample data of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//Test//DTD DITA Mathml Concept//EN" "file:///C:/InfoShare/Web/Author/ASP/DocTypes/dita-oasis/1.2/test/dtd/testConcept.dtd" [
    ]><?ish ishref="GUID-7EF28CDC-9213-4ECC-9EF6-9A49C627151D" version="1" lang="en-US"?>
<concept id="GUID-7EF28CDC-9213-4ECC-9EF6-9A49C627151D" xml:lang="en-US" ishlabelxpath="./title" xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.2" domains="(topic concept)                            (topic hi-d)                             (topic ut-d)                             (topic indexing-d)                            (topic hazard-d)                            (topic abbrev-d)                            (topic pr-d)                             (topic sw-d)                            (topic ui-d)                             (topic sidscDomain-d)                            (topic mathml-d)                            (topic equation-d)   " class="- topic/topic concept/concept ">
```

If i remove the DOCTYPE, it was parsed without a problem by Xerces, but if i leave it there, it fails.

I've created a batch file to call dita-ot:

```
C:\InfoShare\App\Utilities\DITA-OT\test\bin\dita --transtype=%4 --args.input=%1/%2 --output.dir=%3 --dita.temp.dir=%1/temp --args.draft=%5 --clean.temp=%6 --validate=%7 --args.rellinks="nofamily" --logfile %3/%2_%4.log --propertyfile=pdf.properties
```

pdf.properties:

```
args.gen.task.lbl = YES
args.rellinks = nofamily
clean.temp = no
axf.cmd = C:\\Program\ Files\\Antenna House\\AHFormatterV64\\AHFCmd.exe
pdf.formatter = ah
args.grammar.cache=no
validate = no
```

I've actually set the `args.grammar.cache` to `no` and `validate` to `no`, but still it doesn't help at all. Am i doing it wrong? or is there a way to let Xerces ignore DTD validations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me sometime to figure out what's causing the problem. Since we're using SDL Knowledge Center, i thought that they've done some modifications to the old version of dita-ot that we are using. So i downloaded dita-ot 1.8.5 and compare it to our current dita-ot.

When i compare them in WinMerge i see that it really has some changes. In `catalog-dita.xml`, I see some references to the customized dtd components.

```
+   <nextCatalog catalog="../../../../Web/Author/ASP/DocTypes/catalog.xml"></nextCatalog>
+   
+   <!-- Java properties file DTD -->
+   <system systemId="http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd" uri="dtd/properties.dtd"></system>
+
```

This what solved my problem. Hope it can help someone.